# RabbitMQ - Error - Insufficient Security - no_suitable_ciphers

Tags: security, ssl, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ 3.10.6 with Erland 24.0 installed on my desktop PC running Windows 10. I have set up SSL on server and it seems to be configured correctly, but I cannot connect using SSL. Non SSL is working fine. I'm able to connect to an older version of Rabbit MQ 3.7.2 with Erland 19.3 with the client software, using the same client certificates.

I'm getting the error messages:

In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:346 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
no_suitable_ciphers

I've tried installing ciphers through Powershell. My Rabbitmq.conf files is:

`listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.verify               = verify_none
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
ssl_options.cacertfile           = C:\Voyage Manager\RabbitMQ\Certificates\Server\cacert.pem
ssl_options.certfile             = C:\Voyage Manager\RabbitMQ\Certificates\Server\cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile              = C:\Voyage Manager\RabbitMQ\Certificates\Server\key.pem `

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?
Could there be an issue with the certificates, though they work on an older version of MQ?

Thanks
John

Comment: Try with Erlang 25.1.2. There's also a TLS troubleshooting guide - https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html. If none of that works, follow up on the mailing list and I should see your question - https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users